# Condição em query SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Estou com uma dúvida que parece ser besteira mas não estou conseguindo resolver

Possuo uma tabela com os seguintes campos

```
IdInstallation(bigint)|NameInstallation(varchar(255))|IdGroup(FK(bigint))
```

Gostaria de fazer a seguinte consulta nessa tabela

```
SELECT IdInstallation, NameGroup from myTable where IdGroup = NULL
```

Porem essa query não me retorna nada :/

O que eu deveria colocar no lugar de **NULL** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso é preciso usar `... where IdGroup IS NULL`